# Tevo Tarantula incorrectly auto leveling of bed

Tags: calibration, firmware, bed-leveling, tevo-tarantula

I decided to try and setup the bed auto level sensor.

I downloaded this firmware: [TEVO-Tarantula-I3-Marlin-Firmware](https://github.com/JoelLisenby/TEVO-Tarantula-I3-Marlin-Firmware) and followed this tutorial, [YouTube - Setting Up Auto Bed Leveling (Tevo Tarantula)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93p5ziFiGqs).

**Firmware Config files:**

- [configuration.h](https://pastebin.com/g1F2LLgR)
- [configuration_adv.h](https://pastebin.com/fM4b6res)

A few things happened after that:

1. The bed will not level
2. The Z axis goes up to approx. the middle...
3. The printer is in no situation to print

I probably got something wrong...

The machine goes to the leveling points, but is approximately 10 cm above the bed.

Comment: You need to explain what the problem is other than "The bed will not level".  Does it try to level?  Did you send the required code to start the leveling process?

Comment: it's traveling the points of leveling but approximately 10 cm above the bed

Comment: Do you get any Z axis movement?

Comment: yes I do, after it gets to the approx. 10cms above the bde, it can go up a few cms

Comment: Hi, have you resolved your problem at all? If so, would you like to post an answer? If not, could you update your question, with more information?

Answer (score 1):

From your `configuration.h` file you see that (in line 643):

```
#define MANUAL_HOME_POSITIONS
```

is *not* commented out, there is no `//` in front, so this means that manual homing with accompanying coordinates *is* enabled.

This should *not* be enabled, as this setting is used by Delta printers only. This may cause the problems you experience as there may be some sort of a conflict between manual and auto positioning.