# Tevo Tarantula I3 firmware

Tags: marlin, heated-bed, firmware, tevo-tarantula

I've been trying to get something decent printed for days but nothing works! I have a Tarantula Tevo i3 `MKS Base V1.4` and have done a lot of trial & plenty of error. Still I am puzzled to get good prints.

1. What is the stock firmware for a single extruder regular/large bed firmware & how to configure a large bed (if needed to be configured)?
2. Which is the auto bed leveling firmware?

I need help sorting out what's out there. I did not manage to configure a large bed with a single extruder. But did manage to restore firmware with [Marlin-2.0.x](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/)

1. So the [Tevo 3D Printing Store firmware link](https://tevo3dprinterstore.com/pages/tevo-tarantula-firmware) directs to a [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ndykfl1wkw8enpj/AACTlV5qC9dpaJA1PYYLACeha?dl=0) - only dual extruders - both regular & large bed,
2. There is JimBrown's GitHub [MarlinTarantula](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula) - Optimized firmware for RepRap 3D printers based on the Arduino platform,
3. JoelLisenby's GitHub [TEVO-Tarantula-I3-Marlin-Firmware](https://github.com/JoelLisenby/TEVO-Tarantula-I3-Marlin-Firmware).

I followed this, [YouTube - Setting Up Auto Bed Leveling (Tevo Tarantula)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93p5ziFiGqs), for setting up the auto bed leveling sensor but it just got me messed-up even more, see [Tevo Tarantula incorrectly auto leveling of bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4624/tt-is-bed-auto-leveling). I'm just now in the process of trying to manually level the bed and I broke the hot end holder plastic plate...

---

**EDIT**:
The sensor I'm using is [SN04-N Inductive Proximity Sensor - 5mm](https://www.phidgets.com/?tier=3&catid=13&pcid=11&prodid=402)

Comment: I would suggest that you try Facebook groups for support questions. There seem to be some very active ones for the Tevo Tarantula.

Comment: Tried then but got no response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer for **"2)"**:

The default firmware seems to be Repetier. It also includes Bed leveling (see documentation):
https://www.repetier.com/documentation/repetier-firmware/z-probing/

Marlin includes the Auto Bed Leveling feature too. You need to enable it by editing the Configuration.h file.

Bed size settings are there aswell.

"stylesuxx" made a video on how to get Marlin onto the Tevo:

or you can take a look at their website:
http://marlinfw.org/docs/configuration/configuration.html#configuration.h

Autoleveling can be enabeled as well in this file. There is a good video from Thomas Sanladerer on Mesh Bed Leveling:

If you want some help with auto bed leveling it would be nice if you can include what kind of sensor you want to use (inductive, capacitive, microswitch...) and what your prefered type of bed leveling is (mesh 3x3, just z-leveling)...

Comment: Please look at the edit...AFA prefered type of leveling, think I'd go with `mesh leveling` unless you recommend otherwise...

Comment: The `JimBrown-MarlinTarantula github` you pointed out has somewhat different terms to bed leveling - https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/wiki/Bed-leveling-types-(EasyConfig) and I would use th `BILINEAR` method mentioned there

Comment: Your probe is “normaly open”, I don’t know what your microswitches are, but if they are “normaly open” too you can connect both to the same input to have kind of a failsave if the sensor should trigger to late.

Comment: And yes the biliner method is what i meant. How far have you come with your configuration / do you need further help?

Comment: I dropped it...can't seem to find a suitable firmware...they all cause each with it's issues & it seems too much trouble not worth the hassle....+ I couldn't find any decent guide for any firmware. I spent so much time trying to figure this out, repeating the youtubes over & over again - for nothing. Some people say that the `green sensor SN04-N` is crap!!! if you do have suggestions I'd love to hear...thanx

Comment: If you are unsure if your sensor works you could just disconnect it and try to "emulate" it with the normal endstop microswitch instead. You might consider using the "manual mesh bed leveling" instead where the printer moves the nozzle to the desiered positions and you adjust the height with the turning knob and piece of paper. Or if you buy/have an even surface like an aluminium heatbed you might not need the mesh compensation at all. I have an i3 clone with a simmilar board and for me Marlin was the firmware with the least problems. What kind of issue are you running into with marlin?

Answer (score 0):

Tevo Tarantula i3 owners on FaceBook is where I got marlin 2.0. Other things I tried didn't work, but this is working fine if you just want to add auto bed leveling using the standard SN04 sensor.

Comment: Hi Michael, and welcome to 3D Printing.SE! While your addition makes sense, it is as such not fit as an answer, this is more a comment. But, the hint to a FaceBook page has already been given as a comment on the question. Please try to expand the answer by e.g explaining some of the settings you need to change to get auto-bed leveling to work.

Comment: Can you edit your post and provide the link to the Facebook page. Also, preferably, do you have an alternate source, such as a direct link to the source (Github/Gitlab?), as many people (myself included) refuse to use Facebook, in the light of the recent privacy, and wholesale data farming, concerns. Also,. do you mean `Owners` or is that really `owers`? As I don't have a Facebook account I can not check.