# Tevo Tarantula home offset

Tags: heated-bed, firmware, tevo-tarantula

Following [Beny's advice](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/4641/8396), I've just setup [JimBrown-MarlinTarantula](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula) firmware.
However, my `X0` & `Y0` points are off the bed.

When trying to [center my prints](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/wiki/How-to-center-your-prints-(EasyConfig)) & afterwards sending `G1 X100 Y140` to the printer, I am still off center by the margins of the sizes my `X0` & `Y0` points are divided by 2.

What should I do?

Comment: I´m trying to understand, Your printer has a bed for printing of 200 x 280? how far are located the XY end stops from the Bed edge?

Comment: Hi, have you resolved your problem at all? If so, would you like to post an answer? If not, could you update your question, with more information?

Comment: Have you found and fixed the problem? If so, has the answer below led you to the solution? Please vote to accept the answer so this question is not bumped up once in a while and can be removed from the unanswered question list. You may even add your own solution and accept that after 48 hours! If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question.

Comment: The last sentence is a little confusing - is there a comma or a full stop missing? Should it read "...I am still off center. By the margins of the sizes my X0 & Y0 points are divided by 2."? Where exactly is the head coming to rest? You say X&Y are divided by two, does that mean the head is halfway between the center and the corner? A photo or illustration might help.

Answer (score 1):

By adjusting/calibration of the center of the bed you will automatically find the correct offset values.

This is explained in detail in [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/how-to-center-my-prints-on-the-build-platform#answer-6376) to the question [How to center my prints on the build platform?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/6375/5740).