# 3D printer homing issue, nozzle damaging the bed when printing

Tags: marlin, homing, bigtreetech, skr-v1.4

I have a custom Cartesian style 3D printer. The controller board has been upgraded to a BIGTREETECH SKR V 1.4 Turbo. This is a 32 bit board.

Marlin 2.0.3 seemed to build and install with less issues than others. I'm using VS code to work with Marlin. My big problem is with homing all axis. For some reason the Z axis finishes with the extruder 6 mm above the bed. The extruder goes below the bed to start printing. It's damaging the bed. What can be done in Marlin 2.0.3 to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Does this printer have a leveling sensor for automatic bed leveling? Homing is pretty straight forward, the endstops are triggered by forcing the carriage to move to the minimum position on each of the axes. From that point [offsets are defined](/a/6376/5) to take you to the printer origin. Note that the Z is by default raised after homing for many configurations. Please provide some more information, e.g. do you use a leveling sensor, a link to your config and config adv on PasteBin.

Comment: What can be done to fix similar issues? - I provided guidelines in the answer To few information to give more detailed hints.  *(I hope and suppose that author already fixed his issue, and this question could be closed.)*

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason the Z axis finishes homing with the extruder 6 mm above the bed.

If homing Z axes seems proper - i.e. nozzle is "touching" the bed during proces, and not going below the bed level) - then homing may be correct. Otherwise [do troubleshooting](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6376/26170), as has been suggested in comments. Check also the [offset and backoff settings](/a/15353/26170). All these should allow to explain these 6 mm.

> The extruder goes below the bed to start printing.

Follow [this checklist about starting point](/a/15506/26170) to find out any other reasons which could come into play when printing starts.