# What is the correct Marlin firmware setting for Tevo Tarantula with MKS Base V1.2 board

Tags: marlin, firmware, tevo-tarantula, print-axis-offset

I am trying to correct the x&y offsets in the Tevo Tarantula that I got from a friend in order that my printer is not printing over the end.
What I got so far is that I need to measure and then enter the offsets into my configuration.h file, build the firmware and flash it to the board.

Because I do not have and can not find the original firmware I found the repository from [Jim Brown](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula) for the Tarantula.

Looking into the top section of the config file provided by the repo, the board configured is

```
#define MOTHERBOARD BOARD_MKS_GEN_13        // Original controller board with built in stepper drivers. Works with MKS BASE 1.3, 1.4
```

However since the board in my Tarantula has 1.2 on it I checked the boards.h file for MKS but could not find the v1.2 :

```
#define BOARD_MKS_BASE          40    // MKS BASE v1.0
#define BOARD_MKS_BASE_15       405   // MKS v1.5 with Allegro A4982 stepper drivers
#define BOARD_MKS_BASE_HEROIC   41    // MKS BASE 1.0 with Heroic HR4982 stepper drivers
#define BOARD_MKS_GEN_13        47    // MKS GEN v1.3 or 1.4
#define BOARD_MKS_GEN_L         53    // MKS GEN L
#define BOARD_MKS_GEN_L_V2      54    // MKS GEN L V2
#define BOARD_ZRIB_V20          504   // zrib V2.0 control b
```

Any idea, what board configuration would be compatible for 1.2? Or is there any other way to correct the x&y offsets other then compiling them into the firmware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MKS Base v1.2 is basically an Arduino MEGA2560 and a RAMPS1.4 on a single board.

You can use the RAMPS pin designation.

Note that the endstop to origin distances is explained in question [How to center my prints on the build platform? (Re-calibrate homing offset)](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/how-to-center-my-prints-on-the-build-platform-re-calibrate-homing-offset).

In Jims Marlin fork you can find this at:

```
#define X_MIN_POS 0 - XTRA_BED_LEFT
```

and

```
#define Y_MIN_POS 0 - XTRA_BED_BACK
```

Unfortunately, `XTRA_BED_LEFT` and `XTRA_BED_BACK` are defined as zero; this implies that the endstops define the origin (not likely) or it is left as an excercise for you to find out. [This answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/how-to-center-my-prints-on-the-build-platform-re-calibrate-homing-offset/6376#6376) explains how you figure that out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For the RAMPS 1.4 the boards.c file also has multiple configurations.
The board itself has 3 blue power outputs E0, E1, Fan followed by a green power output for the bed.

#define BOARD_RAMPS_14_EFB 43  // RAMPS 1.4 (Power outputs: Hotend, Fan, Bed)
#define BOARD_RAMPS_14_EEB 44 // RAMPS 1.4 (Power outputs: Hotend0, Hotend1, Bed)
#define BOARD_RAMPS_14_EFF 45 // RAMPS 1.4 (Power outputs: Hotend, Fan0, Fan1)
#define BOARD_RAMPS_14_EEF 46 // RAMPS 1.4 (Power outputs: Hotend0, Hotend1, Fan)
#define BOARD_RAMPS_14_SF 48  // RAMPS 1.4 (Power outputs: Spindle, Fan

Comment: @Eike Looks like you have the EFBE option.

Comment: Just greped through the source files for the Easyconfig 1.1 and 2.0 and found only references in some pins_RAMPS files to the EFBE option:

./Marlin/pins_RAMPS.h:  #else    // Non-specific are "EFB" (i.e., "EFBF" or "EFBE") 

sorry for being blind but I am stil not sure what board I should put into the config?

Comment: @Eike EFB is a standard option, the EFBE is an added extra extruder (I understood you had 2 from your comment, but if you are only using 1, you can go for EFB).