# Uneven mesh after perfect auto tramming?

Tags: bed-leveling, mriscoc, tramming

BLTouch enabled Ender 3 w/4.2.2 board running [mriscoc's Professional firmware](https://github.com/mriscoc/Ender3V2S1).

How is it that the auto tramming can report the corners of the bed to be level, and then immediately afterwards it produces this mesh?

What am I missing?

[image: Photo of Ender 3v2 screen showing 'Corners leveled']

[image: Photo of Ender 3v2 screen showing the Mesh Viewer]

Comment: Still, other than a bug in the firmware, why would it do this? Am I misunderstanding tramming vs leveling?

Comment: Leveling is making the print bed parallel with the earth. Tramming is adjusting the print bed to be parallel with the XY-axis. (hope I got that right)

Comment: Have you asked on the Github's discussion page about this issue? Since this is their area of expertise they may have a better idea about what the problem is.

Comment: @agarza Leveling or tramming is explained in [How do you level (or tram) your build surface correctly?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/19082/).