# TronXY X1 Configure bed offsets

Tags: ultimaker-cura, tronxy-x1

I have this printer with the 1.1.6 Marlin. The issue with it is when the printer starts printing the position of the hotend is offset

I am using Cura as the slicer. There, I tried this G-code to configure offset

```
G28 ;Home
G1 Z15.0 F6000 ;Move the platform down 15mm
;Prime the extruder
G92 E0
G1 F200 E3
G92 X5 Y-10
M206 X10
M206 X1 Y1
G92 E0
```

But they are not applied.

What could be the issue?

[image: Photo of a calibration print with some layers shifted]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure the slicer does slice the print object correctly, so beware of the option called "Origin at center" in Ultimaker Cura; this should not be checked for most printers (Delta printers have the center in the middle).

Second, please look into [How to center my prints on the build platform? (Re-calibrate homing offset)](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/how-to-center-my-prints-on-the-build-platform-re-calibrate-homing-offset) to center your print to the build plate.