# Ender 3v2 with CR touch, X and Y axes off on the build plate

Tags: creality-ender-3, calibration, build-plate

I'm new to the 3D printing world. I made a mistake in thinking that my auto leveling wasn't working because of the firmware and reset it to the Creality standard one. After changing the firmware, my X and Y axes have been out. The point hangs over the front section of the plate. I've tried changing this but have been unsuccessful. I have watched many YouTube videos and just don't have a clue what to do!

Can anyone help me how to retune my build plate so that it's centre and uses the max plate dimensions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! This is reaaly not much to work with. What is meant by `The point hangs`, are you implying the nozzle? Most probably your offsets from the endstops are incorrect, this can be easily fixed. Have you seen [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6376/)?